# Centering a pchstack environment that is wider than \textwidth

Tags: cryptocode

I have a pchstack environment from the cryptocode package that is slightly too wide to fit within the text width. I want to center it anyway such that it encroaches on both margins. A minimal example would look like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{pchstack}[boxed]
    \makebox[1.2\textwidth]{}
  \end{pchstack}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Now unsurprisingly this does not actually work. There are several answers here for figures and tables that suggest putting the content into a \makebox[0pt]{...} or an adjustbox. However for reasons I don't know, the pchstack environment can't be but in a box. Making any box around it such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \makebox[0pt]{
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed]
      \makebox[1.2\textwidth]{}
    \end{pchstack}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

leads to pdflatex to complain that

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a
> missing \item.

Is there a different way to center something that's too wide or do I need to get the cryptocode package fixed?

Answer (score 1):

(1) The `boxed` option places the content in a frame box, thus leaving a space equal to `\fboxsep` around it (first box).

(2) To cancel the horizontal stretching and make the box fit the width of the text, use the  key `space` (second box, `space= 2\fboxsep`).

(3) If your content is larger than the width of the text, you can wrap the `\pchstack` in a `minipage` and offset it to the left by half the extra size plus the `\parindent` (last box).

In this simple example, it was done by measuring the width of the longest line, which might not be so simple in a general case, that probably will need a manual correction.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[
n,
operators,
advantage,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,    
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
oracles,
asymptotics,
keys]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{showframe}% only for showing the margins
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{red}{white}} % color the frame boxes

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed]  % default  
        \makebox[1.0\textwidth]{default}
    \end{pchstack}
\end{center}

\begin{center} 
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed, space=2\fboxsep]% eliminate the horizontal expansion    
        \makebox[1.0\textwidth]{space = 2*fboxsep}
    \end{pchstack}
\end{center}    

\newlength{\longline} %measure the longest line
\settowidth{\longline}{$b \sample \bin          (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)         (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample\adv(\secparam, \pk, c)         c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)         b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) $}

\hspace{\dimexpr -\parindent -\fboxsep  + 0.5\linewidth  -0.5\longline}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed, space=2\fboxsep]
    \pseudocode[linenumbering]{
        b \sample \bin          (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)         (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample\adv(\secparam, \pk, c)         c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)         b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state)  \\
        \pcreturn b = b' 
    }
    \end{pchstack}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```